# How to register with the ALDI talk mobile app?

Tags: germany, cellphones, berlin, mobile-operators, registration

I just purchased the ALDI Talk and went through all the steps for the registration including the online identification. Then, I download the iOS app and it asks to provide the 06-nummer in the app. I attached a screenshot for the process. I believe it has to be 10 digit number in total as the app takes a number to that length.

Anyone, please tell me what's that?

Edit, I have taken out the picture as that was for the wrong country/language version of the app.

Comment: I use the iOS app. I believe what happened is the Apple account is created in the US and I just download the app in Germany. So, I mightn't have the access to the German ALDI talk app and instead, downloaded the wrong app (NL). 

This might or might not be the case, but, I read online that someone had to ask a friend to use their German apple account to log in and download the app for them.

Comment: You may need to delete this app and download an German one, as the Dutch and German Aldi talk are different companies, even if they have the same name and same mother company.

Comment: German phone numbers start with `01`. It's tagged with Germany and Berlin, OP just seems to happen to have gotten the Dutch app as maybe their iTunes account is Dutch. It's possible that Medion/ALDI have the app store set up in a way that the app is bound to the account's country. Android Playstore can do that, and I get stopped by this repeatedly as I moved abroad from Germany. I don't know if the iTunes store can do this at all, but if so, you need to activate the SIM in a different way.

Comment: Hi i just bought an Aldi sim card and I have an old phone is it possible to activate my simcard in my old phone and transfer it to my other phone my new phone can't conn to my Wi-Fi and both of them are android phones hope someone can notice my comment any comment related to my comment will be highly appreciated

Comment: If the SIM is activated, this is registered to yourself and not for a specific phone. So, you can use it on another phone later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write this answer as it might help someone in the future - this is slightly weird. My Apple account is created in the USA, so, I assumed if I changed that to Germany, it will surely work out. This turns out not to be true.

Then I used the link posted an earlier answer for the iOS German ALDI talk app. The link is [here](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/aldi-talk/id423979998?l=en&mt=8) and I was not able to open it in the iPhone app store and it provides the message as the app is not available in my region or country. Mind it the iTunes account is set to Germany at the time. I don't get this.

[image]

Finally, I did a Google search and ended up in the page `Chip.de`. The page [link](https://www.chip.de/downloads/Aldi-Talk-iPhone-App_48226178.html) is provided here.

[image]

I clicked the link and it downloaded and opened the same German app provided earlier. This time I was able to install it in the iPhone and rest of the process went seamlessly.

The app has a rating of 2.5 but it works just fine. Only the process of installation is not very convenient.

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer, with the solution that worked for you.

Comment: For the record, Chip is a German language computer magazine, and considered relatively renominated. I would mostly trust them, but don't hold them at high regard.

Answer (score 3):

To top up your account without using an app, you have different option. Those are all listed [on this FAQ page](https://www.alditalk.de/guthaben-aufladen). I will sum them up rather than quoting German text.

- You can set up automatic charging when your balance falls below a certain amount online in your account
- You can buy credit online in your account (or the app)
- You can buy a voucher in any ALDI store in Germany. You do that at the checkout. The voucher will contain a 16 digit number. Vouchers come in 5 Euro, 15 Euro and 30 Euro sizes.

There are several ways to redeem the voucher code:

- Enter the code into your phone like dialing a number:

  Punch in `*104*` followed by the 16 digit number from the voucher followed by a pound `#`. (example: `*104*1234567891234567#`). Then press dial. Your phone will understand this [USSD code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_Supplementary_Service_Data) and do the right thing.
- Call the free hotline by dialing `1155` and press `4`. Then enter the 16 digit number from the voucher followed by a pound `#`. It will read out the numbers to you in German. If you think it's correct, press `1`. The voucher will be credited.
- You can redeem it online in your website account.
- You can use the app.

---

Former answer for future visitors, because I thought this question is about registering the SIM card:

You are using the wrong app. The app you got is for the Netherlands. That's possibly because you are using a Dutch iTunes account. [A quick Google found me this app](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/aldi-talk/id423979998?l=en&mt=8) that appears to be for Germany, but I don't see an activation feature.

---

You can activate your SIM card via the internet. Go to https://www.alditalk.de/simcard/register and enter your **SIM card number** and your **PUK2**.

[image: screenshot of ALI website]

There might be more steps required that I cannot perform, as the text underneath translates to

> You can also use this form to continue an already started registration.

Comment: The SIm is activated and works fine. I look for an iOS app solution for the top up when I won't be in front of the computer.

Comment: @Arefe oh, ok. Your question is tagged with registration, that's why I was confused. I'll update.

Comment: @Arefe please see my update.